# Algorithm for creating mesh from 2D image silhouette

Tags: unity, graphics

I'm looking for an algorithm that can take a 2D image, approximate it's shape and then generate a low poly mesh. Basically, the same what Unity does with sprites when you select tight mesh instead of a rect mesh.

I'd be very thankful for any links that would put me on track to begin my research. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Not really, I don't want to start inventing things and I bet there is some well know algorithm already existing, but I can't seem to find it. Asking if someone can name a few so that I can investigate.

Comment: so far: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_squares